# Controller_Template gives Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, kohana-3

I'm building a KO3 website and I'm creating a new Controller_Template that looks like this:

```
<?php
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Menu extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = "menu/menu";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->User = \Base\User::getLoggedInUser();
    }

    public function action_show() {
        // Do totally nothing
    }
}
```

No rocket science in here. In my APPPATH."/views/menu" directory I have a "menu.php" file that looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "foobar";
```

Impressive right? ;)

When I try to load `http://localhost/menu/show` I get the following error:

```
ErrorException [ Strict ]: Creating default object from empty value

SYSPATH/classes/kohana/controller/template.php [ 44 ]

39   */
40  public function after()
41  {
42      if ($this->auto_render === TRUE)
43      {
44          $this->request->response = $this->template;
45      }
46 
47      return parent::after();
48  }
49 

    SYSPATH/classes/kohana/controller/template.php [ 44 ] » Kohana_Core::error_handler(arguments)

    {PHP internal call} » Kohana_Controller_Template->after()

    SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 1115 ] » ReflectionMethod->invoke(arguments)

    APPPATH/bootstrap.php [ 129 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()

    DOCROOT/index.php [ 103 ] » require(arguments)
```

I have similar function implemented in other controllers and they all work perfectly. So can anybody tell me what is the problem here?

**EDIT**
I dumped the request object in the after method and it is not set, i.e. it has the value null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to call the parent constructor in my overwritten constructor. Changing the code to:

```
class Controller_Menu extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = "menu/menu";

    public function before() {
        $this->User = \Base\User::getLoggedInUser();
    }

    public function action_show() {
        // Do totally nothing
    }
}
```

Fixed my problem.

**EDIT**

Changed the code to suggestions in the comments.

Comment: Use `before()` function instead of `__construct()`

Comment: @biakaveron: Just curious? What is the difference? And why is `before` better than `__construct()`

Comment: there is no significant difference, it is just a hook that is provided for you by Ko3 developers, so you never experience such issues when you forgot to call parent constructor.

Comment: or if Kohana will change constructor's arg list.